# How to calculate difference in time of a dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-filtering

Hi I am trying to calculate time differences for certain tasks in some data I am working on. I have a csv file with a bunch of data, the relevant columns look like below:

| ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 10/08/2021 02:00:05 AM | 10/11/2021 01:00:15 AM |
| 324524 | 10/11/2021 01:00:15 AM | 10/08/2021 02:00:05 AM |

My goal is to create a new file with the row ID, the start date, end date, and the time difference in hours.

So far I have used pandas.to_datetime to change the format of the start date and the end date. Now I am wondering how I can calculate the difference between the two times i.e. (end date - start date) in hours and create a new column in the dataframe to store it in.

Comment: Convert to datetime with `pandas.to_datetime` and perform a simple column-wise subtraction

Comment: Hi, my apologies I should have said that I already did that part. So I have already done the conversion using to_datetime and am having trouble finding out how to store the difference in hours in a new column in a dataframe. Please see my edited question.

Comment: `df['diff'] = (df['End Date']-df['Start Date']).total_seconds()/3600`

Comment: i just tried doing this and now I get an error saying AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Comment: Never mind, doing df['diff'] = (df['ed']-df['sd']).dt.total_seconds()/3600 worked! thanks again :)

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot the dt ;)